# Content Security Policy directive after build to production

Tags: vue.js, webpack, websocket, content-security-policy, vue-cli

im working with websocket using vue2 it work properly before after i move the server to new one my project refused to make a handshake with the channel

Reproduction link

> https://realsportindo.com/event/kejuaraan-kata-virtual-forki-jabar-2020/medals

you can see the log for webscoket blocked

```
Refused to connect to 'wss://example.com/socket//websocket?vsn=1.0.0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

it not happen when production it happen only after build and deploy to production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'".
> Note that **'connect-src' was not explicitly set**, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

says that acting Content Security Policy does not contain `connect-src` directive, but your meta-tag in the HTML code does contain it:
`<meta http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy content="default-src 'self' https: http: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: http: https:; connect-src ws: wss: https: http:">`

This means you have a 2 CSPs published:

- one is through meta-tag in the HTML code
- second is through HTTP-header sending by the server, you can see it in Dev Tool:

[image: CSP via HTTP header]

> 

Since you have 2 different Content Security Policy, all sources should pass unscrathed via [both these policies](https://csplite.com/csp/test327/). But the second one does not allows `wss:` therefore locks it.

You need to delivery CSP in one way: meta tag or HTTP header.

> 

Btw: your CSP rules are so open, that you even do not need a CSP - it does restrict nothing.

Comment: well it work, i tell my devops to change nginx csp, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem: After upgrading to Webpack 5, the `devServer.webSocketServer` was using the default [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) module as server and native WebSockets on the client.

Then, the server tried to connect through a subdomain not listed in my CSP policies, violating the `connect-src` directive.

You can either:

- Modify your meta-tag or,
- Provide a [custom](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwebsocketserver:%7E:text=To%20create%20a-,custom,-server%20implementation%2C%20create) server implementation for `devServer.webSocketServer`, or
- Turn off the server by setting `devServer.webSocketServer: false`. <-- quick workaround